# Word 2010 richtext content control selects all content at once

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-contentcontrol

I have added a richtext content control in a word document 2010 using VSTO (c#)

The document is password protected and every time a user opens the document I set the editor property of the content control to the current user which enables him to edit only that part of the document.

However when I open a previously saved document, and click on the content control I am not able to edit the content of the content control as it selects the complete content all at once and even a single keystroke replaces the complete content.

I have searched high and low for this but do not seem to find a working solution

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to override this behavior by handling the [Entering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.contentcontrolbase.entering.aspx) event and unselect the text. You can do this by changing it's `Range` i think.

You might have set the Text as the `PlaceholderText` and that's why it is removed at the first keystroke because that property is meant for introducing suggestive text (see the search box of StackOverflow, it has a placeholder text "search").

Comment: no. even if i try to do that the focus will be shifted everytime the user enters the control. ofcoz i could have a way around for that but it would get real messy

Comment: so then try to set the range to be to the end of the text, to somehow mimic what happens when the user clicks at the end of the text and the selection is lost and the cursor appears where it should